# Sending encrypted WMI commands to a remote system

Tags: encryption, vbscript, wmi

I found those articles in the Technet database:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393266(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393618(v=vs.85).aspx

Does anybody know more about security level / encryption level of WMI commands (sent to a remote Windows system)?

What does `service.Security_.authenticationLevel = 6` exactly mean?

Could anybody "from outside" catch-encrypt-read the WMI command package which is sent from computer A to computer B? Is the content of the WMI command package "really safe"?

Comment: the page you linked to says "The following table lists the authentication levels you can set. These levels are defined in Wbemdisp.tlb in the enumeration WbemAuthenticationLevelEnum", followed by the meaning of the values. What part of the docs do you have issue with?